# modify QTreeView stylesheet

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pyqt4, pyqt5

I have following style's for tree view and it results like this.

[image]

```
tree_style = """
QTreeView {
    background: #EBFEF4;
    show-decoration-selected: 1;
}

QTreeView::item {
     border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

QTreeView::item:hover {
    background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #e7effd, stop: 1 #cbdaf1);
    border: 1px solid #bfcde4;
}

QTreeView::item:selected {
    border: 1px solid #567dbc;
}

QTreeView::item:selected:active{
    background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #6ea1f1, stop: 1 #567dbc);
}

QTreeView::item:selected:!active {
    background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #6b9be8, stop: 1 #577fbf);
}


QTreeView::branch:has-siblings:!adjoins-item {
    border-image: url(vline.png) 0;
}

QTreeView::branch:has-siblings:adjoins-item {
    border-image: url(:/.png/branch-more.png) 0;
}

QTreeView::branch:!has-children:!has-siblings:adjoins-item {
    border-image: url(:/.png/branch-end.png) 0;
}

QTreeView::branch:has-children:!has-siblings:closed,
QTreeView::branch:closed:has-children:has-siblings {
        border-image: none;
        image: url(:/.png/FolderClosed.png);
}

QTreeView::branch:open:has-children:!has-siblings,
QTreeView::branch:open:has-children:has-siblings  {
        border-image: none;
        image: url(:/.png/FolderOpen.png);
}
"""
```

I want some modification like this image. mainly for folder structure. I tried setting branch image but it is setting at different place.

[image: I want folder icon and plus icon both]

Any help is appreciated..